# Eclipse, jvm and virtual memory overusage

Tags: java, eclipse

I have mysterious issue with eclipse 2019-12 (-Xmx4096m in eclipse.ini):

When it just started the jvm  use not so much memory (top | grep java):

> 9077 legioner  20   0 8317044(VIRT) 652992  52284 S   5,6  4,0(MEM%)   0:48.85
> java

But if only i go to "Window - Web browser" menu in eclipse (without clicking anything):

> 9077 legioner  20   0 89,153g(VIRT) 685228  77956 S   1,3  4,2(MEM%)   0:52.99
> java

pmap shows the max usage of memory by [anon]:

> 00007f0000000000 33554432K rw---   [ anon ]
>
> 00007f0800000000 33554432K [ anon ]

Could someone explain me, why going throught eclipse menu rise usage of virtual memory so dramatically ?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by the non-technical term _"dramatically"_? Eclipse is a Java application and therefore the Java VM is responsible for the memory allocation. Is the memory required by Eclipse or occupied by the Java VM in advance? In the ramp-up phase, the HotSpot VM does this more aggressively than the OpenJ9 VM, for example. Maybe Eclipse is looking for updates in the background causing this. You have to measure Eclipse and the JVM separately, as well as the time dependent course with and without showing the menu. Only displaying a dynamic menu can cause plug-ins to be started.

Comment: Hi!  "dramatically" means in 10719 times. 
What you mean "measure Eclipse and the JVM separately" ? I have only one java application running - eclipse, without starting any projects to run.
"Eclipse is looking for updates in the background" - may be, but the problem begins just after i do something with eclipse - go throught menu, or open preferencies. If i just make change  in project, and build it - everything is ok.
JVM - oracle-8-jdk (build 1.8.0_201-b09).

Comment: Decrease `-Xmx` untile you get an out of memory error to know how much memory is required by a Java application. You can create a heap dump and analyze it e.g. with [Eclipse MAT](https://www.eclipse.org/mat/) to find out how much memory was used by what at that point in time. _Happens after_ does not imply causation. So _dramatically_ is a synonym for _10719 times_? Where can this number be found in the question? Do you want everyone who reads the question to get the numbers from your command line foo and calculate it themselves? Please improve your question instead of adding comments.

Comment: " You can create a heap dump" - i think it's hepless - i watch the jvm with jconsole and saw nothing special in process memory before and after virtual memory usage insreased.